# Is apparmor default deny?

Tags: linux, mandatory-access-control, apparmor

Is apparmor default deny? For example consider the case under SELinux in enforcing mode, where I install a package with no policy associated with it. SELinux's default behaviour is to deny all syscalls that application makes. Does apparmor work the same way, or do you need to explicitly create the policy first and install it.

The FAQ (https://gitlab.com/apparmor/apparmor/wikis/FAQ) says apparmor is default deny if the system is deployed with a complete system policy. What constitutes a complete system policy? Does that mean every process has a corresponding policy?

Is there a way to tell all unconfined processes to be default deny?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its a support/documentation request that would be better suited for a forum dedicated to the software in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how it's deployed. Usually you'll have to whitelist specific calls from your application, but at system level you can apply policies that only a subset of the system is confined.

As perfectly stated by Wiki's FAQ:

> #### Is AppArmor policy Default Deny (White listing)
>
> **Yes,** **and** **no**. AppArmor profiles are based on default deny, that is the
>   rules list what is allowed and everything else is denied. AppArmor
>   policy allows specifying rules to deny actions but these are
>   convenience function to document known bad behaviors, or to specify
>   actions that should never be allowed even if an rule allowing it was
>   added to the profile.
>
> **At a system level AppArmor can be consider either default deny or
>   default allow depending on how it is deployed.** If AppArmor is deployed
>   with a complete system policy so that all tasks are confined then
>   the deployment can be considered default deny. However AppArmor
>   allows policy to be deployed incrementally so that only a subset
>   of the system is actually confined, in this case AppArmor could be
>   considered to be default allow at the system policy level but anything
>   that is confined is confined by policy that is default deny.
>
> #### What is Default Deny (White listing)
>
> Default deny describes the default action applied to a request that
>   is not listed in policy, in this case deny. Policy that is based on
>   default deny provides a list of actions that are allowed (white list)
>   and any thing not listed in policy is denied.
>
> Default deny is considered more secure than default allow because it
>   only allows known good behavior.

[source](https://gitlab.com/apparmor/apparmor/wikis/FAQ#is-apparmor-policy-default-deny-white-listing)

Comment: Yes I read the FAQ. It wasn't clear so I asked here.